# How to compare row data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to check my table data using AND operator in Laravel  and view this like

```
    if(Permission::where('status', '=', '1')->first()) AND (Permission::where('project_id', '=', '$id')->first())return view('collaborators.show')->withProject($project)->withTasks($tasks)->withFiles($files)->withComments($comments)->withCollaborators($collaborators);
else
    return('hi');
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing parethesis after `if` and before `return` keywords.

Here's code with proper syntax for you:

```
if ((Permission::where('status', '=', '1')->first()) AND (Permission::where('project_id', '=', '$id')->first())) {
    return view('collaborators.show')->withProject($project)->withTasks($tasks)->withFiles($files)->withComments($comments)->withCollaborators($collaborators);
} else {
    return 'hi';
}
```

---

I'm not sure but perhaps this is what you wanted to achieve

```
if (Permission::where('status', 1)->where('project_id', $id)->exists()) {
    return view('collaborators.show')
        ->withProject($project)
        ->withTasks($tasks)
        ->withFiles($files)
        ->withComments($comments)
        ->withCollaborators($collaborators);
} else {
    return 'hi';
}
```

Comment: your code is working but $id variable is not identify in Permission::where('project_id', '=', '$id')->first())

Comment: I just fixed syntax. Rest of code is left untouched. You should probably change `'$id'` to `$id` (removing apostrophes)

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure if this is what you want, because I haven't not seen your code.

Answer (score -1):

The below code is formatted properly. It should fix your error

```
if(Permission::where('status', '=', '1')->first() && Permission::where('project_id', '=', '$id')->first()){
    return view('collaborators.show')
        ->withProject($project)
        ->withTasks($tasks)
        ->withFiles($files)
        ->withComments($comments)
        ->withCollaborators($collaborators);
}else{
    return('hi');
}
```

Comment: your code is working but $id variable is not identify in Permission::where('project_id', '=', '$id')->first())

Comment: What was the problem and how does your code solve it?